# jquery setinterval not working

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have this:

```
    $("#nav-reflection li").append("<span></span>");    

    // Animate buttons, move reflection and fade

    $("#nav-reflection a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "-10px" }, 200);
        $(this).parent().find("span").stop().animate({ marginTop: "18px", opacity: 0.25 }, 200);
    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 300);
        $(this).parent().find("span").stop().animate({ marginTop: "1px", opacity: 1 }, 300);
    });

/* =Shadow Nav
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    // Append shadow image to each LI

    $("#nav-shadow li").append('<img class="shadow" src="http://admin.focuswebmedia.com/wp-content/themes/fwm/images/icons-shadow.jpg" width="79" height="19" alt="" />');
    //$("#slider_right").append('<div id="porfolio_contact_text">Our Porfolio&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Us</div>');
    // Animate buttons, shrink and fade shadow

    $("#nav-shadow li").hover(function() {
        var e = this;
        $(e).find("a").stop().animate({ marginTop: "-14px" }, 250, function() {
            $(e).find("a").animate({ marginTop: "-10px" }, 250);
        });
        $(e).find("img.shadow").stop().animate({ width: "80%", height: "20px", marginLeft: "8px", opacity: 0.25 }, 250);
    },function(){
        var e = this;
        $(e).find("a").stop().animate({ marginTop: "4px" }, 250, function() {
            $(e).find("a").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 250);
        });
        $(e).find("img.shadow").stop().animate({ width: "100%", height: "27px", marginLeft: "0", opacity: 1 }, 250);
    });
```

works great on hover. But how do I get this to play automatically every 5 or so seconds? I tried this:

```
window.setInterval(play_ani, 5000);

function play_ani() {
 $j("#nav-reflection a").mouseover();
}
```

But nothing happens...
Any ideas?

Comment: Put an alert inside of `play_ani()`. Is that function getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just trigger the hover event:

```
window.setInterval(play_ani, 5000);

function play_ani() {
 $("#nav-reflection a").trigger('mouseover');
}
```

I think your code does nothing because you are not triggering the effect.

UPDATE - you must trigger mouseover and use $ not $j - example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/qdwZN/3/

Comment: Wrong.  `hover` is not a normal event that can be triggered.

Comment: Hey. Nope, still does nothing

Comment: @David, sorry you have to use mouseover

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti, This still doesnt work for the animation on my side

Comment: @David is the  $("#nav-reflection a").hover(function() { called? (put an alert inside the function to check if it's called).

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti, I put alert('works'); in $("#nav-shadow li").hover(function() { and it alerts on hover. I tried changing the selector to #nav-shadow li and still nothing

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1784/discussion-between-david-and-nicola-peluchetti)

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger the `mmouseenter` event.

However, it would be better to move that code into a separate function and call it from both places:

```
function play(elem) {
    elem.stop().animate({ marginTop: "-10px" }, 200);
    elem.parent().find("span").stop().animate({ marginTop: "18px", opacity: 0.25 }, 200);

$("#nav-reflection a").hover(function() {
    play($(this));
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 300);
    $(this).parent().find("span").stop().animate({ marginTop: "1px", opacity: 1 }, 300);
});

setInterval(function() { play($("#nav-reflection a"); }, 5000);
```